# How to write a function using different algorithms according to the variable value

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I want to write a function using different algorithms according to the value of the argument. This is a simple example

```py
def fun(x):
  if x>2:
    return cos(x)
  else:
    return sin(x)
```

This is what I get
if x>2:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Could you please tag your question with the programming language you are using?

Comment: I am using python

Comment: Okay, could you please add a relevant *tag* and format your code with backticks?

Comment: well, my code would be very simple in any other programming language, just assume

Comment: well, my code would be very simple in any other programming language, just assume def fun(x): if x>2: return 2;else: return 2*x

Comment: My points are about proper formatting: if your code is properly formatted, your question is properly tagged, and your example is minimal and pastable, you are far more likely to get an answer to your question.

Comment: Do you want JS code for a python? JS solution wouldn't work for a python.

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy might solve it.

```py
import numpy as np

def fun(x):
    if x > 2:
        return np.cos(x)
    else:
        return np.sin(x)
```

If you don't have numpy, then in the terminal: `pip install numpy`, or `pip3 install numpy` if you use python3.

---

Sin: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sin.html

Cos: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cos.html

Comment: I do have numpy. Sorry for forgetting np. in the statement of the problem. The problemi is that x is interpreted as an array by python, this is why an error is reported. Later I found out that a solution can be y=np.cos(x);y[x<=2]=np.sin([x<=2]); return y